# Having trouble with Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock Final in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, output

So I am a student who is working on his final and I have been pulling examples from other programs we have already done.  I can get everything to work but the results its a simple paper rock scissor lizard spock game but im not sure why the results are not working

```
<html>
<head>
<script type ="text/javascript">

var gameResults     // Game Results
var playerChoice    // Players choice
var BR = "<br />";  // Line break
var ES = "";        // Empty space
var PA = "<p />";   // full paragraph break
var NL = "\n";      // New Line

function winResults(string)
{
gameResults = wcType;
}


function setChoice(pcType)
{
playerChoice = pcType;
}

function displayResults()
{

var name = document.RockPaperSpockForm.name.value;
var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.2) 
        {
        computerChoice = "Rock";
        }
    else if (computerChoice <= 0.4) 
        {
        computerChoice = "Paper";
        } 
    else if (computerChoice <= 0.6) 
        {
        computerChoice = "Scissors";
        } 
    else if (computerChoice <= 0.8) 
        {
        computerChoice = "Lizard";
        } 
    else 
        {
        computerChoice = "Spock";
        }
var compare = function(playerChoice, computerChoice)
    {
    if (playerChoice === computerChoice) 
        {
        winResults(Tie);
        }
    else if (playerChoice === "Rock") 
        {
        if (computerChoice === "Scissors") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Paper") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Lizard") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            }
        }
    else if (playerChoice === "Paper") 
        {
        if (computerChoice === "Scissors") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Rock") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Lizard") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            }
        }
    else if (playerChoice === "Scissors") 
        {
        if (computerChoice === "Paper") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Rock") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Lizard") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            }
        }
    else if (playerChoice === "Lizard") 
        {
        if (computerChoice === "Scissors") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Rock") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Paper") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            }
        }
    else if (playerChoice === "Spock") 
        {
        if (computerChoice === "Scissors") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Rock") 
            {
            winResults(Win);
            } 
        else if (computerChoice === "Lizard") 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            } 
        else 
            {
            winResults(Lose);
            }
        }
    }
compare(playerChoice, computerChoice);

alert("Hello! " + name + " you have chosen " + playerChoice + " and the computer has chosen " + computerChoice + "!" + NL + "You " + gameResults + "!");
}

</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="Azure">
<h3>Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock!</h3>
<form name="RockPaperSpockForm" action="">

<strong>Enter your name:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="name" value="Name" size="40"><p />

<strong>Select Paper, Rock, Scissors, Lizard, or Spock:</strong><br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Paper" onclick="setChoice(this.value)" /><img src="PaperThumb.JPG"><p />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Rock" onclick="setChoice(this.value)" /><img src="RockThumb.JPG"><p />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scissors" onclick="setChoice(this.value)" /><img src="ScissorsThumb.JPG"><p />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Lizard" onclick="setChoice(this.value)" /><img src="LizardThumb.JPG"><p />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Spock" onclick="setChoice(this.value)" /><img src="SpockThumb.JPG"><p />

<input type="button" name="displaybutton" value="Go" onclick="displayResults()" /><p />
<textarea name="messageBox" readonly="true" value="" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea><br />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what i was going for is the results would set the variable inside the function to Tie, Win, Lose and then i could just attach it to the alert but its not working showing up as undefined. Any help would be appreciated I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you change this line of code:

`function winResults(string)`

to read:

`function winResults(wcType)`

You will also need to fix your calls to `winResults` so that the parameter that you pass is a string literal in each case -- right now all of these calls are written as though they pass a variable named `WIN`, `LOSE` or `TIE`.  For example, where you currently have:

`winResults(TIE)`

you should change that to:

`winResults("TIE")`

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try

Comment: Thank you very much sir its working great, guess i needed a fresh pair of eye cant believe i missed the " " lol

Comment: My pleasure #SOReadyToHelp -- welcome to StackOverflow.  Fresh-eyes are a great tool for finding bugs and StackOverflow is a great place to find fresh-eyes.  Please mark my answer as 'Accepted' -- this will also give you +2 rep points.